# purging mechanism / deletion of messages from slack in bulk

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there anyway to delete bulk of messages from the slack application in one go, without paying for any package?

I need to introduce a mechanism which will delete the messages filed in the slack after certain period of time and this mechanism will work after certain interval

Answer (score 2):

There is no API method for bulk operations. You have to keep track of a list of messages and invoke `chat.delete` for each on your own (in the code of your Slack App).